# dhclient took minutes to get an IP

Tags: dhcp

For some reason my mini-computer had no IP address, so I performed `sudo ifdown eth2` followed by `sudo ifup eth2`. What followed was a 5 minute grudge match of my client fighting the server to see who could be more stubborn. At the end it finally got an IP address, but not one that it had been requesting. What would cause this sort of fighting, and how can I reconfigure to avoid it?

`dhclient.conf` follows the log output.

```
Nov  5 14:23:36 nvidia dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6 (xid=0x1c08c5d8)
Nov  5 14:23:42 nvidia dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12 (xid=0x1c08c5d8)
Nov  5 14:23:54 nvidia dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0x1c08c5d8)
Nov  5 14:23:56 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x1c08c5d8)
Nov  5 14:23:56 nvidia dhclient: DHCPOFFER of 172.20.40.71 from 172.20.40.1
Nov  5 14:23:56 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0x1c08c5d8)
Nov  5 14:23:56 nvidia dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x19021763)
Nov  5 14:23:56 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x19021763)
Nov  5 14:23:56 nvidia dhclient: DHCPOFFER of 172.20.40.71 from 172.20.40.1
Nov  5 14:23:56 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0x19021763)
Nov  5 14:23:59 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x19021763)
Nov  5 14:23:59 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0x19021763)
Nov  5 14:24:04 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x19021763)
Nov  5 14:24:04 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0x19021763)
Nov  5 14:24:11 nvidia dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x37e59f2f)
Nov  5 14:24:11 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x37e59f2f)
Nov  5 14:24:11 nvidia dhclient: DHCPOFFER of 172.20.40.71 from 172.20.40.1
Nov  5 14:24:11 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0x37e59f2f)
Nov  5 14:24:14 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x37e59f2f)
Nov  5 14:24:14 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0x37e59f2f)
Nov  5 14:24:17 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x37e59f2f)
Nov  5 14:24:17 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0x37e59f2f)
Nov  5 14:24:24 nvidia dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x41702f49)
Nov  5 14:24:27 nvidia dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6 (xid=0x41702f49)
Nov  5 14:24:27 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x41702f49)
Nov  5 14:24:27 nvidia dhclient: DHCPOFFER of 172.20.40.71 from 172.20.40.1
Nov  5 14:24:27 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0x41702f49)
Nov  5 14:24:30 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x41702f49)
Nov  5 14:24:30 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0x41702f49)
Nov  5 14:24:33 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x41702f49)
Nov  5 14:24:33 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0x41702f49)
Nov  5 14:24:41 nvidia dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x43246040)
Nov  5 14:24:41 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x43246040)
Nov  5 14:24:41 nvidia dhclient: DHCPOFFER of 172.20.40.71 from 172.20.40.1
Nov  5 14:24:41 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0x43246040)
Nov  5 14:24:44 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x43246040)
Nov  5 14:24:44 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0x43246040)
Nov  5 14:24:51 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x43246040)
Nov  5 14:24:51 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0x43246040)
Nov  5 14:25:00 nvidia dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x6caca5f6)
Nov  5 14:25:01 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x6caca5f6)
Nov  5 14:25:01 nvidia dhclient: DHCPOFFER of 172.20.40.71 from 172.20.40.1
Nov  5 14:25:01 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0x6caca5f6)
Nov  5 14:25:04 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x6caca5f6)
Nov  5 14:25:04 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0x6caca5f6)
Nov  5 14:25:11 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x6caca5f6)
Nov  5 14:25:11 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0x6caca5f6)
Nov  5 14:25:19 nvidia dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x1f6963d4)
Nov  5 14:25:19 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x1f6963d4)
Nov  5 14:25:19 nvidia dhclient: DHCPOFFER of 172.20.40.71 from 172.20.40.1
Nov  5 14:25:19 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0x1f6963d4)
Nov  5 14:25:22 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x1f6963d4)
Nov  5 14:25:22 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0x1f6963d4)
Nov  5 14:25:30 nvidia dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x7c056f7e)
Nov  5 14:25:31 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x7c056f7e)
Nov  5 14:25:31 nvidia dhclient: DHCPOFFER of 172.20.40.71 from 172.20.40.1
Nov  5 14:25:31 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0x7c056f7e)
Nov  5 14:25:34 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x7c056f7e)
Nov  5 14:25:34 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0x7c056f7e)
Nov  5 14:25:39 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x7c056f7e)
Nov  5 14:25:39 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0x7c056f7e)
Nov  5 14:25:48 nvidia dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xab17b6d)
Nov  5 14:25:48 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0xab17b6d)
Nov  5 14:25:48 nvidia dhclient: DHCPOFFER of 172.20.40.71 from 172.20.40.1
Nov  5 14:25:48 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0xab17b6d)
Nov  5 14:25:51 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0xab17b6d)
Nov  5 14:25:51 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0xab17b6d)
Nov  5 14:25:54 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0xab17b6d)
Nov  5 14:25:54 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0xab17b6d)
Nov  5 14:25:58 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0xab17b6d)
Nov  5 14:25:58 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0xab17b6d)
Nov  5 14:26:07 nvidia dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x7c7ee3b0)
Nov  5 14:26:07 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x7c7ee3b0)
Nov  5 14:26:07 nvidia dhclient: DHCPOFFER of 172.20.40.71 from 172.20.40.1
Nov  5 14:26:07 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0x7c7ee3b0)
Nov  5 14:26:10 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x7c7ee3b0)
Nov  5 14:26:10 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0x7c7ee3b0)
Nov  5 14:26:18 nvidia dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x7a8ec50)
Nov  5 14:26:18 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x7a8ec50)
Nov  5 14:26:18 nvidia dhclient: DHCPOFFER of 172.20.40.71 from 172.20.40.1
Nov  5 14:26:18 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0x7a8ec50)
Nov  5 14:26:21 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x7a8ec50)
Nov  5 14:26:21 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0x7a8ec50)
Nov  5 14:26:29 nvidia dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x53e10240)
Nov  5 14:26:29 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x53e10240)
Nov  5 14:26:29 nvidia dhclient: DHCPOFFER of 172.20.40.71 from 172.20.40.1
Nov  5 14:26:29 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0x53e10240)
Nov  5 14:26:32 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x53e10240)
Nov  5 14:26:32 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0x53e10240)
Nov  5 14:26:40 nvidia dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x3920325e)
Nov  5 14:26:40 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x3920325e)
Nov  5 14:26:40 nvidia dhclient: DHCPOFFER of 172.20.40.71 from 172.20.40.1
Nov  5 14:26:40 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0x3920325e)
Nov  5 14:26:43 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x3920325e)
Nov  5 14:26:51 nvidia dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x296d0094)
Nov  5 14:26:51 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x296d0094)
Nov  5 14:26:51 nvidia dhclient: DHCPOFFER of 172.20.40.71 from 172.20.40.1
Nov  5 14:26:51 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0x296d0094)
Nov  5 14:26:54 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x296d0094)
Nov  5 14:26:54 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0x296d0094)
Nov  5 14:26:58 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x296d0094)
Nov  5 14:26:58 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0x296d0094)
Nov  5 14:27:09 nvidia dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x62ff65c6)
Nov  5 14:27:09 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x62ff65c6)
Nov  5 14:27:09 nvidia dhclient: DHCPOFFER of 172.20.40.71 from 172.20.40.1
Nov  5 14:27:09 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0x62ff65c6)
Nov  5 14:27:12 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x62ff65c6)
Nov  5 14:27:12 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0x62ff65c6)
Nov  5 14:27:19 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x62ff65c6)
Nov  5 14:27:19 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0x62ff65c6)
Nov  5 14:27:31 nvidia dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x3c915dc9)
Nov  5 14:27:31 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x3c915dc9)
Nov  5 14:27:31 nvidia dhclient: DHCPOFFER of 172.20.40.71 from 172.20.40.1
Nov  5 14:27:31 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0x3c915dc9)
Nov  5 14:27:34 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x3c915dc9)
Nov  5 14:27:35 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0x3c915dc9)
Nov  5 14:27:39 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x3c915dc9)
Nov  5 14:27:39 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0x3c915dc9)
Nov  5 14:27:49 nvidia dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x68eff7c8)
Nov  5 14:27:49 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x68eff7c8)
Nov  5 14:27:49 nvidia dhclient: DHCPOFFER of 172.20.40.71 from 172.20.40.1
Nov  5 14:27:49 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0x68eff7c8)
Nov  5 14:27:52 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x68eff7c8)
Nov  5 14:27:52 nvidia dhclient: DHCPNAK from 172.20.40.1 (xid=0x68eff7c8)
Nov  5 14:27:56 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.40.71 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x68eff7c8)
Nov  5 14:28:04 nvidia dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x53f01e35)
Nov  5 14:28:06 nvidia dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 172.20.44.15 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x53f01e35)
Nov  5 14:28:06 nvidia dhclient: DHCPOFFER of 172.20.44.15 from 172.20.40.1
Nov  5 14:28:06 nvidia dhclient: DHCPACK of 172.20.44.15 from 172.20.40.1
Nov  5 14:28:06 nvidia dhclient: bound to 172.20.44.15 -- renewal in 1733 seconds.
```

Here's the `dhclient.conf` (with most commented-out lines removed):

```
# Configuration file for /sbin/dhclient, which is included in Debian's
#       dhcp3-client package.

option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of unsigned integer 8;

send host-name = gethostname();
send dhcp-requested-address 172.20.44.15;
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
        domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
        dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.domain-search,
        netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
        rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers,
        dhcp6.fqdn, dhcp6.sntp-servers;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it something that happens each time ?

It looks like the dhcp server try to give the address 172.20.44.71 to your interface eth0 which refuses it. Then, when the server offer the address 172.20.44.15 there is an DHCPACK accepting this one.

In your configuration file, there is this line:

> send dhcp-requested-address 172.20.44.15;

Do you really need/want to use this ip address?
Have you tried to remove this line and make some tests?

Comment: I do not need that specific address. I want to get a consistent address (without a static IP); this is why I added that requested address line to the config. It does not always do this long fight, but it's done it twice now. I will try removing that line and trying again. However: I don't understand the exchange at all. It looks to me like my client repeatedly requested `.40.71`, the server offered it, and then the server disallowed it?